# Can't use sympy parser in my class; TypeError : 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I wrote some code for calculating the differential equation and it's solution using sympy, but I'm getting an error, my code : ( example )

```
from sympy.parsing import sympy_parser
expr=1/2
r='3/2'
r=sympy_parser(r)
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: It's because module objects are not callable.  Maybe you wanted `sympy.sympify(r)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sympy_parser` is a *module*, and modules are not a *callable*. What you want is [`sympy_parser.parse_expr`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html):

```
>>> from sympy.parsing import sympy_parser
>>> r ='3/2'
>>> r = sympy_parser.parse_expr(r)
>>> r
3/2
```